# Использование GET параметра в форме php

Tags: php, get

Интересует следующий вопрос: есть форма авторизации в файле index.php, как сделать так, чтобы эта форма стала доступной после введения GET параметр?

То есть, имеется 'index.php', а нужно сделать, чтобы форма выводилась после 'index.php?login=yes'?

Понятно, что это будет конструкция if-else (if (isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'yes')), а что дальше в условие прописать, чтобы проверка происходила прямо на странице?

Comment: Обычно index.php — это некий диспетчер, который принимает параметры и выполняет нужные действия. Сама же форма, или блок ответа, то есть, то что нужно выводить в зависимости от параметров, выносятся отдельными  php-файлами. Соответственно в вашем условии будет что-то вроде require('form-yes.php');

Comment: @MAX правильно понимает адекватню архитектуру приложения, но если Артему нужен просто по условию выводить или не выводить блок разметки, то надо подробней почитать про синтаксис PHP. навскидку условие в разметке, если таковая есть в `index.php`: `<div><?php if((isset($_GET['login']) && $_GET['login'] == 'yes')) :?><form>форма вывдтся только при условии</form><?php endif;?></div>`